# Teradata query pagination - batch every 1000 records

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I've this Teradata query:

```
WITH ID(ROW_NUM) AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRSN_ID) AS ROW_NUM
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE ACTIVE_IND = 'Y' 
    GROUP BY PRSN_ID
)
SELECT ROW_NUM-ROW_NUM MOD 2 AS FirstIndex,
ROW_NUM-(ROW_NUM-1) MOD 2 AS SecondIndex
FROM ID
WHERE ROW_NUM MOD 2=1
```

This query will generate an ID column, and the result will be something like this:

```
FirstIndex    SecondIndex
0             1
2             3
4             5  
.             .
.             .
etc           etc
```

I would like to change the selection to be a batch through a 1000 records like below:

```
FirstIndex    SecondIndex
0             1000
1001          2000
2001          3000  
3001          4000
.             .
.             .
etc           etc
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is way to complex:

```
   ROW_NUM-1 AS FirstIndex,
   ROW_NUM   AS SecondIndex
```

To get your requested range you simply need to modify the calculation, e.g.

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN ROW_NUM = 1 THEN 0 ELSE SecondIndex-999 END AS FirstIndex,
   (ROW_NUM+2)/2 * 1000 AS SecondIndex
FROM ID
WHERE ROW_NUM MOD 2=1
```

But what do you want to do with that result, batch *what*?

Edit:

It's still unclear why you need a 2nd table to calculate the ranges, but this creates ranges starting from 1 for any pagesize of *n* rows:

```
WITH ID(ROW_NUM) AS 
(  -- just to get some rows
    SELECT day_of_calendar AS row_num
    FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR
    WHERE row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 10
)
SELECT 1000 AS RowsPerPage,
   Row_Num AS page_num,
   rownum_to - (RowsPerPage-1) AS rownum_from,
   page_num * RowsPerPage AS rownum_to
FROM ID
GROUP BY page_num
ORDER BY page_num

RowsPerPage     page_num     rownum_from     rownum_to
       1000            1               1          1000
       1000            2            1001          2000
       1000            3            2001          3000
       1000            4            3001          4000
       1000            5            4001          5000
       1000            6            5001          6000
       1000            7            6001          7000
       1000            8            7001          8000
       1000            9            8001          9000
       1000           10            9001         10000
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I would like to use this in Talend to be able to batch a 1000 records at a time and send it through a web service request. I noticed that your query jumps to 2000 in your second record, also your query generates 76 records (pages) whereas I've only 151 records on MyTable righ now.

Comment: Also this won't work when you have a 1000 or 2000 of records, can you please help?

Comment: My query returns exactly your expected result. I still don't fully understand what you want to do: You got another Select with thousands of rows with a sequence number generated by ROW_NUMBER? And you want to use your query to define the "pages" to be returned?

Comment: Yes, this is true, the idea is to query the pages at the beginning, and then Talend will loop through the pages to fetch a 1000 records for every page and send it through a SOAP service call. But I just tried your query, the first row is missing and it doesn't work when we have like a 1000 or 2000 records.

Comment: Yes dnoeth, I do need the second table because I needed a sequential ID to preform pagination. I'll try your updated query and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Of course you can apply the rownum_from/to calculation without a table, Talend needs to remember the last id anyway...

Comment: Right, I tried your latest query and it works perfectly, but the last piece is if I have 3500 records, when I run your query I would like it to be to show 4 records, 1 to 1000 and 1001 to 2000 and 2001 to 3000 and 3001 to 4000 which is 4 pages, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try the below query once, this will give you the desired sequence.

```
select ROW_NUM,FirstIndex, coalesce(case when SecondIndex<1000 then (SecondIndex+2000) else (SecondIndex+1000) end,FirstIndex+1001) as SecondIndex from 
(SELECT ROW_NUM,
case when (FirstIndex < 1000) then (FirstIndex+1001) else (FirstIndex+1) end as FirstIndex,
(min(FirstIndex) OVER(ORDER BY FirstIndex ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING))  SecondIndex
FROM (Select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRSN_ID)-1) AS ROW_NUM,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRSN_ID)-1) AS FirstIndex from Mytable GROUP BY PRSN_ID) A) B
order by ROW_NUM;
```

Comment: thanks!, but this doesn't work well, it doesn't start with 0 or 1 - 1000 for the first page/range, also imagine if I have 3000 records I should only see 3 records/pages/ranges, make sense?